# Converting Enumeration Object to List More Than Once

Tags: java, list, enumeration

Why does converting Enumeration object to List more than once result to empty list after the first one?

Here is an example:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("page.info1", "page.info2");
Enumeration<String> stringEnumeration = Collections.enumeration(strings);
List<String> se1 = Collections.list(stringEnumeration);
List<String> se2 = Collections.list(stringEnumeration);
System.out.println(se1 + "|" + se2);
```

List **se2** is empty.

```
[page.info1, page.info2]|[]
```

Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Probaly because `stringEnumeration` is exhausted after `set1` is created.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the incredibly outdated `Enumeration` class?

Comment: Yes, @Kayaman. To read properties keys in Liferay: 
`Enumeration<String> propertiesKeysEnumeration = this.getResourceBundle(request.getLocale()).getKeys();`